# Vtiger 6.3 Mail scanner hangs

Tags: php, crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

Dears, i am using vtiger 6.3

I have a problem regarding to mail converter scan

- Outgoing mail configured correctly
- CRM sending emails
- Mail box added correctly to mail converter module
- IMAP module is installed and enabled at server
- Ports are correct within the module files

the problem is when i press "Scan now" button, it just loading and don't do anything else

Comment: i think you have to share your log file which contains log for issue while you do scan.

Answer (score 0):

Please turn off error reporting on your webserver
Add the following code into config.inc.php

```
@error_reporting(0);
```

MailManager module send request on index.php and receive response in JSON String format. if your server return error Vtiger javascript files cannot parse Invalid Json String. and page hang on loading page.

Also you can change error reporting on config.inc.php to see whats happening

```
ini_set('display_errors','on'); version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) : error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);   // DEBUGGING
```

Also you must Enable log error on server for check error logs
[How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)